# Python Tkinter with Asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, canvas, tkinter, python-asyncio

I have a simple update function for a Tkinter canvas that I need to use asynchronously. Here is the function so far:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def update(self):
    self.canvas_lock.acquire()
    yield from self.canvas.delete(tk.ALL)
    for i in range(len(self.bitmap)):
        for j in range(len(self.bitmap[i])):
            if self.bitmap[i][j].color != None:
                x0 = i * self.dimensions["rect"][0]
                y0 = j * self.dimensions["rect"][1]
                x1 = (i+1) * self.dimensions["rect"][0]-1
                y1 = (j+1) * self.dimensions["rect"][1]-1
                color0 = self.bitmap[i][j].color
                color1 = self.bitmap[i][j].outline
                yield from self.canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=color0, outline=color1)
    self.canvas_lock.release()
```

By the way, this is inside of a class with `self.root = tk.Tk()`, and `self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root)`. `self.bitmap` is a 2d array of class instances that have a `color` property that's a tuple, ex: `(0, 255, 0)` is green(RGB colors). `self.canvas_lock` is just an RLock.

The function should acquire a lock, this is just so that I can have multiple of these functions running, and others that need access to the canvas without any errors. The next thing it should do is run through a 20x20 bitmap of class instances that have a set color, then draw it onto the canvas. This works without asyncio but I need it to run asynchronously, right now it doesn't draw anything on the canvas and just returns the function. How do I get it to draw on the canvas while being asynchronous?

Comment: Why do you `yield from` self.canvas.delete and self.canvas.create_rectangle? They are not coroutines, are they? Please provide a minimal working example. What threads are running in your application that cause you to need both asyncio and a threading.RLock?

Comment: I tried using `yield from` because I need to clear the canvas before I can draw on it, my understanding of Python asynchronous is that I have to put the `yield from` before any function I want to execute before moving on to other functions. The lock is working fine, I've already tested the lock. If I take out the decorator and `yield from`s then the canvas works fine, but after adding everything it doesn't draw anything on the canvas.

Comment: Please provide a minimalworking example and be more specific in your title of the question.